# How to check all elements in an array same as some element in the other array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a question about How to check all elements in an array same as some elements in other array.

array1= [[1,2], [2,3], [3,3]]
array2 = [[1,2],[2,3]]

so in this case it will return true, because all the elements in array2 are same as array1.

Doses anybody some solution

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use `Array.prototype.some()` to calculate intersection between your two arrays. A nested `.some()` is needed, because we need to stringify the arrays and compare them as JSON string, since `[1,2] !== [1,2]`, for example.

See proof-of-concept code below:

```js
const array1 = [[1,2], [2,3], [3,3]];
const array2 = [[1,2],[2,3]];
const array3 = [[3,4],[4,5]];
const array4 = [[3,3]];

function isIntersecting(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.some(x => {
    return arr2.some(y => {
      return JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y);
    });
  });
}

console.log(isIntersecting(array1, array2));  // Should return true
console.log(isIntersecting(array1, array3));  // Should return false
console.log(isIntersecting(array2, array3));  // Should return false
console.log(isIntersecting(array1, array4));  // Should return true
```